# Routes outside navigation guards vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an application in vue with vue router that works correctly, also in the router I use navigation guards to protect my routes, the problem is that now I want to have routes or components that work outside the navigation guards, for example a page of password recovery that the user receives a link and can access it directly, my problem is that i want to access to a recovery password direct from a external link it always redirects me to the login, I share my code:

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/check-balance',
    name: 'check-balance',
    component: CheckBalanceComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/check-payment',
    name: 'check-payment',
    component: CheckPaymentsComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/payment-disabled',
    name: 'payment-disabled',
    component: DisabledMakePaymentComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/handle-payment',
    name: 'handle-payment',
    component: HandlePaymentsComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/handle-report',
    name: 'handle-report',
    component: HandleReportsComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/user-profile',
    name: 'user-profile',
    component: UserProfileComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  }, 
  {
    path: '/recover-password', 
    name: 'recover-password',
    component: RecoverPasswordComponent,    
    meta: {
      free: 1 //this outside navigation guards
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/recover-link', 
    name: 'recover-link',
    component: RecoverLinkComponent,
    meta: {
      free: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    meta: {
      free: 1
    }
  },
  
  {
    path: '/help',
    name: 'help',
    component: HelpComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.free)){
    next()
  } 
  
  else if(store.state.user && store.state.user.user_type == 1){
    next()
  }

  else {
    next({
      name: 'login'
    })
  }
})

export default router
```

Comment: Can you show the path of the link you're trying to use?

Comment: http://localhost:59876/api/Users/password-recovery

Comment: It looks like that's an api path rather than a front-end route.  If so, this indicates that your server is redirecting even */api* directory traffic to the app, which is wrong.  You need to configure the server not to do that.  For help with that, you'll need to post details about what server you're using and how the redirection has been configured